# GLSL uniform only being updated by unrelated calls

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have an extremely basic GLSL program which is failing to properly update a uniform value after the first draw call. No errors are received from `glGetError`, no errors are reported in the info logs when compiling and linking the shaders, and all uniform locations are valid.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat3 nmv;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main()
{
    v_normal = normalize(nmv * normal);
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform vec3 lightDir;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 materialColor;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main()
{
    vec3 n = normalize(v_normal);
    float nDotL = max(0.0, dot(n, lightDir));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(materialColor * lightColor * nDotL, 1.0);
}
```

Rendering code:

```
glUseProgram(program);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp);
glUniformMatrix3fv(nmvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, nmv);
glUniform3fv(lightDirLoc, 1, lightDir);
glUniform3fv(lightColorLoc, 1, lightColor);

for (auto mesh: meshes)
{
    glUniform3fv(materialColorLoc, 1, mesh.color);
    mesh.draw();
}
```

The rendered meshes are all drawn in the color of the first mesh, indicating that after initially setting the `materialColor` uniform, the subsequent calls to change the uniform are ignored. However, here is a list of special conditions which independently allow the uniform to be updated properly:

- Calling `glUseProgram(program)` within the loop.
- Setting the `mvp` or the `nmv` uniforms within the loop.
- Setting the `lightDir` uniform within the loop.
- Removing one of the `uniform vec3`s from the shader program.

Please note that setting the `lightColor` uniform within the loop will **not** update the `materialColor` uniform. I have also checked `GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM` within the loop, and the shader remains bound throughout.

I have been trying to fix this for hours and absolutely cannot find the issue. This shader setup is so simple that I don't believe it's a driver bug. I'm using OpenGL 2.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M.

Here is a call trace for a single frame:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(1);
glUniformMatrix4fv(1, 1, 0, 0x7fff55512550); // mvp
glUniformMatrix3fv(5, 1, 0, 0x7fff55512528); // nmv
glUniform3fv(0, 1, 0x7fff55512670);          // lightDir
glUniform3fv(9, 1, 0x7fff555124e8);          // lightColor

// Mesh 0
glUniform3fv(8, 1, 0x7fab820cd7ec);          // materialColor
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x00000000);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x0000000c);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 21);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Mesh 1
glUniform3fv(8, 1, 0x7fab823000bc);          // materialColor
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x00000000);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x0000000c);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 24);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Mesh 2
glUniform3fv(8, 1, 0x7fab8231f8fc);          // materialColor
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x00000000);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x0000000c);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 21);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Mesh 3
glUniform3fv(8, 1, 0x7fab820cf41c);          // materialColor
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x00000000);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointerARB(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 24, 0x0000000c);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

CGLFlushDrawable();
```

**EDIT:** Here is the code used to obtain the uniform locations. It is performed after the shaders have been compiled and linked, and all uniforms are verified to be valid.

```
GLint mvpLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp");
GLint nmvLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "nmv");
GLint lightDirLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lightDir");
GLint lightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lightColor");
GLint materialColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "materialColor");
```

Comment: It seems to me that the only difference between the lightColor and lightDir uniforms is their location in the shader. Have you tried switching their places and seeing if lightColor indeed does trigger the change? I would also try to see if an ATI or Intel GPU produces the same behavior.

Comment: I've just tried switching their order, and the behavior remains exactly the same. `lightColor` still does not trigger the change. Unfortunately I don't have access to another GPU at this time.

Comment: I noticed that swapping either the order of declaration, or their positions in the operations resulted in their uniform locations remaining unchanged.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. :) Is it possible for you post a complete working sample I can compile/run on different hardware/driver platforms? Or would it too much work to extract from your current application?

Comment: It would be rather difficult to extract and provide you with a working sample from this application. However if you would like to attempt to duplicate the behavior, you should be able to use the call trace data to perform the exact same operations.

Comment: Here is a simple test you can do ensure the material color is actually not being updated:  set gl_FragColor to the material color.  From what I see right now, I'm not convinced your conclusions are correct.  I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying this test would prove conclusively that the material color is in fact not being updated.

Comment: I've tried that, and the material color is not changing.

Comment: Can we see the code you use to find the uniform locations?

Comment: The code used to obtain uniform locations has just been added. As you can see, it's very standard. I'm now definitely suspecting a driver bug.

Comment: This is a very old question, did you ever solve it? I'd first go with after looking at the impossible, is mesh.color actually changing? And pointing to the right value? Especially after aeskreis last test.

Comment: did you try to move the glGetuniformLocation calls to start of each frame (not call only once) ... some drivers especially ATI can change locations and have many weird behaviour if there is any memory leak in your code

Comment: @ChrisHoward after your added the CPU side mesh draw related code its clear that you hardcoded all VBO and uniform positions but your fragment and vertex shaders have not static locations anywhere ... see [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) and look for `glGetUniformLocation` usage ... also in shaders you can state something like this: `layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;` but that is for more recent GLSL in older version it might be a bit different ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Sometimes driver will optimize some of your uniforms (even if it should not especialy with older drivers). to test that try to use your material color in vertex shader (copy it to some varying variable and in fragment shader use that varying variable instead of uniform, that sometimes works for me,... of course it lower performance a bit)
2. try to use different profile version. In some cases newer drivers do not emulate older versions properly. Had you try core profile ? (i know its very tricky to implement with older code)
3. you can try nvemulate to test different driver settings

sometimes forgotten glEnd(); makes a lot of trouble try to add this code before your frame rendering code:

```
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
glEnd();
... here comes your rendering code
```

if this helps than you forgott to call glEnd(); somewhere or have glEnd; instead of glEnd();

**[Edit1]**

After your added the **CPU** side mesh draw related code its clear that you hard-coded all **VBO** and `uniform` positions but your fragment and vertex shaders have not static locations anywhere see

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

and look for `glGetUniformLocation` usage. Also in shaders you can state something like this:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
```

but that is for more recent **GLSL** in older version it might be a bit different and too lazy to search for syntax and keyword...

Comment: A `glEnd` problem would have triggered a GL error, which the OP states to have checked.

Comment: OP is using modern GL, glEnd is deprecated

Comment: @mackycheese21 well that is specified now but not back in the days when this was answered,... and as the OP author did not notify I have no means to know this then ... still `glEnd` is just a portion of the answer ... after looking at the call trace it is most likely a problem with locations as all the VBOs and uniforms are hardcoded in CPU side code but not in GLSL part ...

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't see the post dates.

Answer (score 1):

Still not solved?

what is the type of mesh.color

looking at the addresses passed into the call trace they seem rather high, perhaps you should be passing in an address to the data not the actual data, 0x7fab823000bc

glUniform3fv(materialColorLoc, 1, &mesh.color);
perhaps try hard coding and using glUniform3f()

Answer (score 0):

From all the addresses in the trace I'd guess any vec3 you send to GL are of type `float name[3]`, aren't they?  Assuming this I cannot spot an error in your code.  As you stated there's no error-state returned by glGetError, it MUST be a driver bug.

I saw in the trace that you start every mesh doing a glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) - this is not really necessary.  But anyhow, I cannot imagine this to be the source, either.

Sadly, you cannot test stuff like glBindUniformLocation before linking, as that is not part of OpenGL.

My experience shows: if you issue a glUniform3fv and all parameters are correct, then the uniform is updated and that change is visible right away.  As that is not the case, here, it must be a driver bug, so the only things you could possibly do is: add other unnecessary calls to your rendering loop to make the change visible (which you already did if I read this correctly).